# Why doesn't CLang++ optimize the loop while G++ does?

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, compiler-optimization, clang++

## Source Code

I calculate the sum of a billion numbers generated by `uniform_real_distribution`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::mt19937;
using std::random_device;
using std::uniform_real_distribution;

int main()
{
    random_device rd;
    mt19937 gen(rd());
    uniform_real_distribution<float> dis(-1, 1);
    float result = 0;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 1E9; ++i)
    {
        result += dis(gen);
    }
    cout << result << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

## Issue

When I compile the code with `clang++ -O3 --std=c++11 main.cpp`, it works for a minute. When I compile with `g++ -O3 --std=c++11 main.cpp` it works for 6 seconds. Also, I've used `g++-5` and `g++-6`, and got 3 seconds.

When I use `-O1` optimization in `g++`, it optimizes the code, and only without an optimization flag it produces the program, which takes almost two minutes to complete. Application produced with `clang++` without an optimization works slightly faster than the one produced by `g++` without optimization.

## Question

Can I make the `clang++` to optimize the code as good as `g++`? Is the performance issue my fault, or `clang++`'s?

## Additional Information

`g++ -v` output

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu3.2' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-7 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.2.0 (Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu3.2)
```

`clang++ -v` output

```
clang version 4.0.1-6 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.1
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.4.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.2.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.1
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.4.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.2.0
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.2.0
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64
Found CUDA installation: /usr/local/cuda, version unknown
```

Comment: [Read the assembly](https://godbolt.org/g/GUG7xQ), ponder your findings and reformulate the question. Then it might be answerable.

Comment: Weird.  When I run the code on wandbox it runs for clang but times out for gcc using -02

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`g++` and `clang++` have different default "inlining levels".

Often `g++` is more aggressive. In this case the different threshold seems to interfere with other optimizations.

You can control the inlining behavior with `-mllvm -inline-threshold=` (also see [LLVM Development](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/llvm-dev/GpU79q9JzJI)).

Here

```
clang++ -O3 --std=c++11 -mllvm -inline-threshold=15000
```

works quite well and produces a sensible speedup (for "real code" the size of the executable could grow a lot).